# Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir problema?

Tags: c

> #### Ação
>
> Receba dois inteiros do usuário, o primeiro sendo o dígito que se quer saber quantas vezes aparece e o segundo sendo o número do contato.
>
> #### Entrada e Saída
>
> **Entrada:**
>
> Valor inteiro A (entre 1 e 9).
>   Valor inteiro B.
>
> **Saída:**
>
> Número de vezes que o dígito A aparece em B

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
   {

       int contaDigitos = 0, valor;
       scanf("%d", &valor);
       if (valor == 0) contaDigitos = 1;
       else
            while (valor != 0)
           {
             contaDigitos = contaDigitos + 1;
               valor = valor / 10;
           }
      printf("%d\n", contaDigitos);
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: debora, apesar de ter um pessoal com olho bem treinado aqui, tente explicar melhor que problema você está tendo, para que o pessoal possa te ajudar sem ter que descobrir/adivinhar, [editando sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/329723/edit) (provavelmente a ajuda vai vir mais rápida assim) - aproveite e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [leia aqui como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: algo como: _"estou fazendo um programa que faz X - ao compilar, o erro é Y - ou, ao executar, ao invés do resultado esperado, ele mostra Z"_ - ah, e **seja bem vinda ao stackoverflow!** =)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro que você deveria ler dois valores A e B, mas você só está lendo o B.

Dentro do `while`, você deveria verificar se o dígito do `valor % 10` é o valor do A e só com isso incrementar o `contaDigitos`.

O seu `if (valor == 0) contaDigitos = 1;` também não tem sentido. Basta usar o `while` que está no `else`.

Também dá para simplificar `valor = valor / 10;` para `valor /= 10;` e `contaDigitos = contaDigitos + 1;` para `contaDigitos++;`. Recomendo também renomear a variável `valor` para `b` para ficar de acordo com o enunciado do exercício.

Seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int contaDigitos = 0, a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b % 10 == a) contaDigitos++;
        b /= 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n", contaDigitos);
    return 0;
 }
```

Com a entrada `5 57565503` ele produz a saída `4`. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/fmiwno).

Ah, isso não vai funcionar para valores de B maiores que 2147483647 devido a um overflow, mas acho que para os propósitos do seu exercício, isso está ok.